# Incrementing on Date based on another field SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How is it possible to work with Dates, so I can use the number of days to add that number to another date

For example, I need to increment 1 day for each number included in Loan_period to Loan_Date and the result should be in the Return_Date

```
CREATE TABLE Book
  (
    Resource_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    Loan_Period int (40) NOT NULL,
    noTimesLoaned int NOT NULL
  );

CREATE TABLE Loan
  (
    Loan_No   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Loan_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Return_Date DATE,
    Resource_ID INT NOT NULL,


  );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sample data would certainly help, but - in *date arithmetic*, in Oracle a simple `date datatype value + number` results in number of **days** added to that date. For example:

```
SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate + 2 as today_plus_2_days
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           TODAY_PLUS_2_DAYS
------------------- -------------------
15.12.2021 14:02:09 17.12.2021 14:02:09

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Book
(
  Resource_ID   INT
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT book__rid__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Title         VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  Loan_Period   int NOT NULL,
  noTimesLoaned int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Loan (
  Loan_No     INT
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT load__ln__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Loan_Date   DATE NOT NULL,
  Return_Date DATE,
  Resource_ID CONSTRAINT loan__rid__fk REFERENCES book
              NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can create a book:

```sql
INSERT INTO book(title, loan_period, notimesloaned)
VALUES ('ABC', 14, 0);
```

Then you can use `INSERT INTO Loan (...) SELECT ... FROM book ...` to transfer the correct book details into the `loan` table:

```sql
INSERT INTO loan (loan_date, return_date, resource_id)
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) + loan_period,
       resource_id
FROM   book
WHERE  resource_id = 1
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM loan;
```

Outputs:

> | LOAN_NO | LOAN_DATE | RETURN_DATE | RESOURCE_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 2021-12-29 00:00:00 | 1 |

*Note: You should not have a `noTimesLoaned` column in the `Book` table; if you want to get that information it should be generated using a `COUNT(*)` query on the `Loan` table (possibly in a view).*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f01dcbf77cbb3b04983fb234eb01605b)*